# Retrieving user created roles and user info in Azure

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database, user-administration

I used to following to create a role in Azure SQL database, grant permissions to the role and assigned the role to the user:

```
CREATE ROLE [DepartmentReadOnly] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

GRANT SELECT ON tblDepartment TO DepartmentReadOnly

CREATE USER [user1] FROM LOGIN [user1];
EXEC sp_addrolemember DepartmentReadOnly, user1;
```

Now what sql do I use to retrieve the DepartmentReadOnly role name and permissions from the database as well as user1 user information including which roles user1 belongs to?

There is no sys.server_principals system view showing up in Azure so I am lost. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked:

```
SELECT p.[name] as 'Principal_Name',
CASE WHEN p.[type_desc]='SQL_USER' THEN 'User'
WHEN p.[type_desc]='DATABASE_ROLE' THEN 'Role' END As 'Principal_Type',
--principals2.[name] as 'Grantor',
dbpermissions.[state_desc] As 'Permission_Type',
dbpermissions.[permission_name] As 'Permission',
CASE WHEN so.[type_desc]='USER_TABLE' THEN 'Table'
WHEN so.[type_desc]='SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' THEN 'Stored Proc'
WHEN so.[type_desc]='VIEW' THEN 'View' END as 'Object_Type',
so.[Name] as 'Object_Name'
FROM [sys].[database_permissions] dbpermissions
LEFT JOIN [sys].[objects] so ON dbpermissions.[major_id] = so.[object_id] 
LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] p ON dbpermissions.  [grantee_principal_id] = p.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN [sys].[database_principals] principals2  ON dbpermissions.[grantor_principal_id] = principals2.[principal_id]
WHERE p.principal_id > 4
```

http://elena-sqldba.blogspot.com/2015/06/retrieving-all-user-created-users-roles.html

Answer (score 1):

"select * from sys.sql_logins" used as sys.server_principals in azure, and you must run query in master db

Comment: sys.sql_logins only gives me the logins, not roles.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for these catalog views in your user database:

- [sys.database_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) has the role (see the bottom of the page for an example to list all permissions by joining with [sys.database_permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx)).
- [sys.database_role_members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189780.aspx) has the role memberships.

Comment: As tmullaney states, what you want is [sys.database_principals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx), [sys.database_role_members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189780.aspx), and [sys.database_permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx). Permissions are recorded in sys.database_permissions.

`select * from sys.database_principals
select * from sys.database_role_members
select * from sys.database_permissions`

Comment: I selected name from sys.database_principals  and DepartmentReadOnly role is not there...

Comment: OK, I found the role name when I ran select * from sys.database_principals on my dastabase and not on master database. But how do I retrieve group members for my group? the usernames are not in database_principals table

Comment: sys.database_role_members contains the principal_id for both the role and the member user, so you can join with sys.database_principals to get both the role names and the user names.

Comment: Ex: `select dp_user.name as username, dp_role.name as role from sys.database_role_members drm
inner join sys.database_principals dp_user on dp_user.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals dp_role on dp_role.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id`